# How can I prevent an application (or user) from changing the screen resolution?

Tags: windows, windows-7, resolution

I am searching for an option to disable resolution changes by certain programs or users.

In example I have a media player who automatically changes the resolution depending on the inserted medium. Since the results are poor, I want to disable this functionality. Since there is no according option in the player settings, I thought about creating a user who is lacking the rights to change the resolution.

But I have no idea how to do that. Alternatively I would also be completely satisfied if you know a way of restricting these rights on a per-program basis. Actually any solution is welcome.

I'm am running Win7 Professional.

Comment: Which player is it that changes the resolution ?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I have a similar problem with a game that uses a non-standard way to change resolution that isn't captured by the GPU, and it seems like no one here actually answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to configure a shortcut key combination to switch the resolution back to your preferred settings after the media player changes them.

I can confirm that [HotKey Resolution Changer](http://funk.eu/hrc/) from funk.eu does change the display resolution in Windows XP. It claims to work in Windows 7 as well.

[image]

Highlights:

> - Sits silently in the tray
> - Define 2 to 9 shortcuts for different resolutions
> - Switch resolution with just a keypress!
> - Resolutions below 640×400 and frequencies above 120 Hertz are excluded.

You may also be able to use AutoHotKey [script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic8355.html&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=resolution&start=0) for this.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works!! Great. You are a day saver :-)

Answer (score 4):

as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/18677/windows-xp-prevent-users-from-changing-screen-resolution) is mentioned , i think this is the best way :

> You could disable the settings tab for users as policy:

`Local Security Policy > User Config > Admin Templates > Control Panel > Display > Hide Settings Tab`
[image]
[image]

> Here is the MSDN documentation for this settting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811676.aspx`

Comment: This is your answer

Comment: But does that prevent changing the resolution via other means?

Comment: After rereading the queston, preventing Media Player from changing your resolution is not going to happen if it was a user that might happen but not a appication

Comment: Yeah, as stated before, this does only prevent users from changing the resolution. Programmms are still able to modify it. Anyway thanks for this very detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a video card from either NVIDIA or AMD, they should have control panel settings that allow you to force resolutions and aspect ratios.

NVIDIA Control Panel:
Under **Display** > **Adjust desktop size and position**:

1. Select scaling mode: **No scaling**
2. Perform scaling on: **GPU**
3. Check **Override the scaling mode set by games and programs**

Don't know for AMD cards.

This solution is unfortunately heavy-handed, and not the per-program or per-user solution you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Unfortunatelly the media player can still change the resolution. I don't know how, but it does. I double checked, I applied all the settings you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution is to get with the developer of the media player and have them fix the issue a media player should not be causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I agreee. I am already in contact with them and they are trying to fix the issue. But the release of a patch takes them at least a month, so I had to look for an intermediate solution.